# problem with a compound nspredicate

Tags: iphone, core-data

what is a problem with this predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(category like[cs] %@) AND (aroundme==YES)",category];
```

?
Thks.

Comment: Please improve your question. What is your problem?

Comment: this predicate return an empty result ..but really there is many rows that respond to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

excuse me the problem was not there .. i did'nt add the category attribute to the DB

Answer (score 3):

[There is no such thing as an `[s]` comparison modifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-218407).  The only ones are `[c]`, `[d]`, or `[cd]`.

Comment: @Dingua then you need to provide a lot more information. Give us examples of the objects this is supposed to be filtering, perhaps the .h? Show us more of the surrounding code.  Simply posting a predicate and saying "it doesn't work" isn't helpful.

Comment: the .h is@interface Promo : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * adresse;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * aroundme;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * category;

@end

Comment: excuse me the problem was not there .. i did'nt add the category attribute to the DB .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to instead pass in [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] to aroundme==%@ like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(category like[cd] %@) AND (aroundme==%@)",category, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

That is unless you are looking for the string 'YES'.  Then, the resulting predicate should quote YES.

Comment: excuse me stephen but this was resolved , and this is my mistake.(u can see my comment in the answer of dave De Long)

Comment: @Dingua The question was not marked solved when I posted.  I wanted to point out another mistake (in addition to "[cs]") in the formatting of your original question that hadn't been pointed out.  Keep in mind that this post is for you and everyone else to learn from.

Comment: u have reason stephen .. excuse me every one!